# Open file in New Window in Textmate

Tags: macos, textmate

Is there an easy way to open a file in a new window (as opposed to a new tab) in Textmate?  The wokraround I've been using is to open the project in a second window, but there must be a better way?

Comment: Yeah I'd love to have a key command that opens a file in a new window.

Answer (score 2):

check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465577/how-to-view-a-file-in-a-new-window-in-textmate

> Right click on the file in the drawer and there is an option to open in new window.

Comment: Is it possible to open a file per default in a new window?