# How to force Textmate to open file in New Window, always?

Tags: macos, textmate-2

How to force Textmate (is for Macs only) to always open file in a New Window without setting projectDirectory = $CWD... which kinda screws up project search.

Yes, I'm willing to go as far as compiling my own build, but would love to know where that piece of code may be if there is no other option. No, I do not want to use another text editor.

And Yes, I've already searched the whole internet before asking here.

Comment: What OS? And have you seen this question: https://superuser.com/questions/58448/open-file-in-new-window-in-textmate?rq=1

Comment: The mailing list might be more helpful than Stack: http://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate

Comment: @music2myear macosx. Yes, hence "always" in the question.

Comment: Please add the OS to the question. Adding it as a tag is also helpful so that people who watch for MacOS questions will look at queues of questions tagged. It is best that all relevant information be in the main question body. Editing is good and, frankly, expected as comments clarify the original question and improve it.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath That's extremely helpful, thank you.  However, I voided and went straight to #freenode, no respond so far, but I'm hopeful.  Thanks again!